# The REST API endpoint /items(<itemId>) returns data.d undefined

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

Trying to get value of Message column from the 1st list item in GreetMe list:

```
function getMessage() {
var requesturi = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('GreetMe')/items(1)?$select=Message";
var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
var message = "";

    $.ajax({
        url: requesturi,
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        headers: requestHeaders,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {  
           alert('Success: '+ data.d.Message);
           message=data.d.Message;
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('error: '+data);
        }
    });

    return message;
}
```

What is missing here? Pls advise

Comment: Are you sure the first item in the list actually has ID 1? Maybe someone deleted the item with ID 1, so it can't be retrieved by using `/items(1)`...

Comment: If you do not specify `ContentType: application/json` in the headers, the response could be in XML, and not in JSON. So data.d could be undefined.